# Github.io image links

Tags: css, image, github

I have an issue with the image paths on github.io it seems that it can't display images from my github repository **(yes I checked spelling with case sensitivity)** and I'm kind of out of ideas maybe you'll spot my mistake. If you want to check the linking go to src/css/inc/variables.scss. Thanks for your help! 
Repo: [enter link description here](https://github.com/B0r3d/PDH)
Website: https://b0r3d.github.io/PDH/

**Answered below**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok apparently it took 1h to parse those images so they display. Answer to the problem with github images would be either you made some spelling mistakes (github is on linux which results in case sensitivity) or your images are beeing processed for quite a long time

Comment: Interesting finding ... and welcome to *upvote* levels btw ;-)